# Continuity of a function and its derivative

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Does $f'$ being continuous on $(a,b)$ imply that $f$ is also continuous on $(a,b)$?

I think this is probably quite a straightforward question but it's key to solving the problem that I'm working on.

Comment: If a function is differentiable, then it is continuous (even if the derivative is not continuous).

Comment: Continuity of $f'$ is irrelevant. If $f'$ exists everywhere in $(a, b)$, $f$ is continuous on $(a, b)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't even need the continuity of $f'$.  The fact that the limit $f'(x) := \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ exists for every $x \in (a,b)$ implies that $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$.

To see this, we just need to show that $\lim\limits_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$ for every $c \in (a,b)$, or in other words, $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} f(x+h) = f(x)$ for every fixed value of $x \in (a,b)$.  Since $$|\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} - f'(x)| $$ tends to $0$ as $h$ goes to $0$, so does $$|h| \cdot |\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} - f'(x)| = |f(x+h) - f(x) - h f'(x)|$$  But $f'(x)$ is a fixed number, so $h f'(x)$ becomes negligible, so you can see that $|f(x+h) - f(x)|$ must also tend to $0$ as $h$ goes to $0$.